# Aggregating millisecond time series to a second using xts library

Tags: r, time-series, aggregate-functions, xts, milliseconds

I need to aggregate 1sec time series from 100 millisecond time series. I use a function `to.period()` in R xts, having converted the data into xts format first.
The error is: unsupported type.

```
x <- xts(data, order.by = as.POSIXct(data$Time, format = "%H:%M:%S.%ms"))
to.period(x, period = "seconds", k=1)
Error in to.period(x, period = "seconds", k = 1) : unsupported type
```

Same error when I try period = minutes and higher.

```
             Date           Time   Price     Amount
<NA> "2014/10/26" "17:30:12.500" "1.268"  "1000000"
<NA> "2014/10/26" "17:33:28.900" "1.268"  "1000000"
<NA> "2014/10/26" "17:33:52.600" "1.268"  "1000000"
```

Mac OS

Is this error because my data is in milliseconds format or is there any other reason? What can I do to fix the error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several issues with your code. I suggest you spend a few minutes reading the zoo and xts vignettes to better understand these two classes.

Assuming your `data` looks like:

```
data <- structure(list(Date = c("2014/10/26", "2014/10/26", "2014/10/26"),
  Time = c("17:30:12.500", "17:33:28.900", "17:33:52.600"), 
  Price = c(1.268, 1.268, 1.268), Amount = c(1000000L, 1000000L, 1000000L)),
  .Names = c("Date", "Time", "Price", "Amount"), class = "data.frame", 
  row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Your call to the `xts` constructor will not work.

```
x <- xts(data, order.by = as.POSIXct(data$Time, format = "%H:%M:%S.%ms"))
```

`data$Time` is just a time, not a datetime, so `as.POSIXct` will use today's date. But that doesn't work because you specified the format incorrectly (`"%ms"` isn't a valid format, see `?strptime`), which causes all the resulting values to be `NA`.

Even after correcting those two issues, your code still will not work because `data` contains several types of data (character (factor?), double, integer) and xts objects are a matrix with an index attribute, and you can't mix types in a matrix. So you need to exclude the Date and Time columns from the coredata of the xts object. And you need to specify the `format` argument of `as.POSIXct` correctly.

```
x <- xts(data[,c("Price", "Amount")],
  order.by=as.POSIXct(paste(data$Date, data$Time), format="%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%OS"))
```

Now `to.period` will work:

```
to.period(x, "seconds")
#                     x.Open x.High x.Low x.Close
# 2014-10-26 17:30:12  1.268  1.268 1.268   1.268
# 2014-10-26 17:33:28  1.268  1.268 1.268   1.268
# 2014-10-26 17:33:52  1.268  1.268 1.268   1.268
```

If you want to aggregate the Amount column as volume, you need to rename it before calling `to.period`.

```
colnames(x)[2] <- "Volume"
to.period(x, "seconds")
#                     x.Open x.High x.Low x.Close x.Volume
# 2014-10-26 17:30:12  1.268  1.268 1.268   1.268    1e+06
# 2014-10-26 17:33:28  1.268  1.268 1.268   1.268    1e+06
# 2014-10-26 17:33:52  1.268  1.268 1.268   1.268    1e+06
```

Comment: Joshua, thanks a lot for your help. I've corrected my mistakes as you said but still have the same error. (had to replace data$Date and data$Time with data[,1] and data[,2])Also, time format="%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%OS" does

Comment: Sorry, I'll continue here...Also, the format ="%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%OS" doesn't show milliseconds, but %OS1 (or OSn for the fractions of a second) does not work here. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @EniyaAlby: You need to set  `options(digits.secs=3)` if you want milliseconds to be printed by default. Just because they don't print doesn't mean they're not there. ;-)

Comment: Thanks @Joshua, now I can see the milliseconds.  But I still get the same Error in to.period(x, "seconds") : unsupported type after I have corrected the mistakes that you showed. x <- xts(data[,c("Price", "Amount")],
         order.by=as.POSIXct(paste(data[, 1], data[,2])), format =  "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%OS")
 x.sec <- to.period(x, "seconds")

Comment: @EniyaAlby: then you need to make sure the `Price` and `Amount` columns are numeric, not character, *before* you create the xts object.

Comment: Now it works. I made all the mistakes one can possibly make with xts, and Joshua corrected them all. Thanks a lot @Joshua, I highly appreciate your help.